# Be able to select which type of link in Hyperlink add box

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, hyperlinks

Please could the automatic link adder have options to chose either citation style:

```
[link text][1]

[1]: http://example.com
```

or inline style:

```
[link text](http://example.com)
```

[image]

I personally prefer to use Citation, but [some posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445) need to have inline style.

I would also like it to remember the last used setting per site, so I can have different style preferences per site.

Comment: Quite minor, in the very few cases where inline link is required, just do it manually. (agree it's nice and useful, just don't expect it to get high priority)

Comment: Yeah but it would just be nice to have the option - especially for people who prefer inline over citation all the time.